# Google app engine and Google checkout notifications error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-checkout

I'm just having problems getting the [custom order processing tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Custom_Processing_How_To.html) to work.
Has anyone had luck with this?

I get the following errors:

```
Error for /myapp
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/checkout/sdk/commands/EnvironmentInterface
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2406)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2716)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:343)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    ......
```

Any suggestions?
Just trying to receive notifications of new purchases at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the jar that contains EnvironmentInterface is in WEB-INF/lib, as well as on your classpath.